# EditText in ListView behavior

Tags: android

I found FocusChange of EditText behavior different when EditText in ListView.
My testing program has two EditText.  Once on the Activity, another one in the listview.

The following is the log when I type text in normal Editext and lost focus

```
10-11 16:26:32.440: INFO/Test(4317): 1:onFocusChange:false
10-11 16:26:32.490: INFO/Test(4317): 2:onFocusChange:true
```

The following is the log when I type text in Editext in list view and lost focus

```
10-11 16:28:17.551: INFO/Test(4317): 2:onFocusChange:false
10-11 16:28:17.609: INFO/Test(4317): 2:onFocusChange:true
10-11 16:28:17.679: INFO/Test(4317): 2:onFocusChange:false
10-11 16:28:17.719: INFO/Test(4317): 1:onFocusChange:true
```

The log is told me that EditText in list view will trigger more then 1 times Focus Change.
Is this behavior is bug or not

I using android 4.0.3 sdk.

The following is XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:id="@+id/listView"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

here is code

```
public class EditTextActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.edit_text_activity);

        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        editText.setWidth(200);
        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                Log.i("Test", "1:onFocusChange:" + hasFocus);
                editText.setText("");
            }
        });

        ListView listView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 1;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int i) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int i) {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
                LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(viewGroup.getContext());

                final EditText editText = new EditText(viewGroup.getContext());
                editText.setId(1);
                editText.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(200,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                        Log.i("Test", "2:onFocusChange:" + hasFocus);
                        editText.setText("");
                    }
                });

                layout.addView(editText);

                return layout;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: How do you make it lose focus? Do you tab the other EditText?

Comment: I touch another EditText.

Answer (score 0):

The edittext losing and regaining focus is not a bug; whan you press a key on the keyboard that key gets the focus, but when you let go of the key the edittext gets the focus back. What are you trying to do? Is the edittext used for search and added in the listview?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use getter setter method for this. i have also tried this with the help of the link below.
https://looksok.wordpress.com/2012/11/03/android-custom-listview-tutorial/
Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the follow line in your activity with your editText

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Then your listView must have

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
```

Source : http://androidtechnicalblog.blogspot.ch/search/label/ListView

Answer (score -1):

add below in manifest for your activity-

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: I added android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in manifest for my activity but the behavior is same. It still not solve